# Nodeclipse set path Node and Express

Tags: node.js, nodeclipse

I installed node.js on Ubuntu 12.04 using this command

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nodejs
sudo npm install -g express
```

The I installed Nodeclipse to Eclipse Juno. How can I set Node path and Express path ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Click Window -> Preferences -> Nodeclipse.

Node Path

```
/usr/bin/nodejs
```

Express Path

```
/usr/lib/node_modules/express/bin/express
```